# how to match string in a list

Tags: linq

I'm having a list of string like

`var target = new List<string>() { "C", "C-sharp", "java" };`

I'm having a string request = **"C is a programming language"**

This list should match with the string and should return

`C,C-sharp`

How can i do this?

Comment: Why do you need regex for this? `string.StartsWith` is fine.

Comment: Your question is vague, but answered both in the comments and in the first answer. It's  probably inefficient to use regex so you should avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq and [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
var filtered = target.Where(str => str.Contains("C"));
```

Another option, without Linq, is to change the existing list using [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
target.RemoveAll(str => !str.Contains("C"));
```

If you really need a regex (for something more complex), you may also use:

```
Regex validate = new Regex(".a.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 var filtered = target.Where(str => validate.Match(str).Success);
```

Comment: he means selecting first index of word if match 'c', not any word contains 'c' in the list

Comment: @mekici - That is pure speculation, but you can easily adapt it. `:)` (hmm... I hope I'm not getting downvoted for a stupid "error" as this, the real question is about filtering the list...)

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution with linq

```
var m = from t in target
                where t[0] == 'C'
                select t;
```